# Writing Modules?

Tags: go

I've been searching Google up and down, but I can't find any documentations on Modules and how to write them.

So, My question is, how do you write Modules in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word module has many different meanings. What is your definition?

Take a look at Go packages. Read [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html). Read the [Go package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/). Since Go is open source, look at the [Go package source code](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg) for examples.

Comment: Apparently, writing Packages in Go is as easy as writing a Go app... :D

Answer (score 2):

screencast on writing Go packages:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDWBJOXs_iI